# timeout setting inside the web.config's <authentication> tag

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session, forms-authentication

I am working on an asp.net mvc-4 web application hosted under IIS-8 and windows server 2008 R2.
now for the asp.net mvc i am using form authentication, which is integrated with our active directory.
here is the related entities inside our  web.config :-

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <add name="TestDomain1ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, &#xA;            Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="TestDomain1ConnectionString" connectionUsername="*********" connectionPassword="******" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />

  </providers>
</membership>

<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="40320" />
</authentication>
```

now my question is about the timeout parameter inside the `<forms>`. now i understand this setting as follow:-

When the user first login to the web application , he will enter a username & password. if his credentials are valid, a browser cookie will be generated to him, and saved inside the browser cache. now since i have specified a timeout="40320". this means that the browser cookie will expire after 40320 minute ?? is this correct ? so if the user try to access the system after 40320+ minute from his first login, then IIS will see that the passed cookie is expired and will logout the user .. is this correct ?

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/1d3t3c61(v=vs.85).aspx

Optional attribute.
Specifies the time, in integer minutes, after which the cookie expires. If the SlidingExpiration attribute is true, the timeout attribute is a sliding value, expiring at the specified number of minutes after the time that the last request was received. To prevent compromised performance, and to avoid multiple browser warnings for users who have cookie warnings turned on, the cookie is updated when more than half of the specified time has elapsed. This might cause a loss of precision. The default is "30" (30 minutes).